# Changing target specific option in gcc

Tags: gcc

I want to edit few target specific option of my gcc, madx,mhle,march,mtune etc.
Can I change them through command line?
I am using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? Please elaborate, what is it you're trying to do? What is the problem you want so solve?

Comment: I am working on reproducible build creation, the same source code with same build system generating different .so files on two different machine. They have different cpu(different version of intel family). when I see the gcc target specific option on both machine they are different(using gcc -march=native -Q --help=target), I am just trying to make all gcc option exactly same for both the machine just to see if they produce the same output. when I say change I mean I want enable -madx in my gcc and so on.

Comment: All "built-in" options can be overridden by passing the arguments on the command line. I also recommend [the GCC online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/) for more information about options and command-line arguments.